# DHTMLXGantt, need to add button to lightbox save for index

Tags: html, dhtmlx

Is there a way to add index while saving to dhtmlxgantt for tasks through lightbox save press?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this worked for me.

gantt.attachEvent("onLightboxSave", function (id, task, is_new) {

```
gantt.moveTask(task.id, parentIndex + 1, grandparentID);

gantt.hideLightbox();


        });
```